# Incremental updates table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm dealing with some hi volume, but not very mutable data, and want to maintain a table of changes (call it `update_history`), as well as a table which holds the current data (call it `current_data`).

- `current_data` contains: `id` (which is unique), `value`, `tstamp` (the current timestamp)
- `update_history` contains: `id` (which, again, is unique), `value`, `tstamp` (for all the updates), `delete`

Say I have certain data with `id` = 1. At time 0 it is initialized to 10, at time 5 it is changed to 2, at time 8 deleted, and at time 10 again set to 10. After all this, I'd like the `update_history` to contain:

```
Id Value Stamp Delete 
1    10     0     0
1     2     5     0
1     2     8     1
1    10    10     0
```

While I can select from `update_history` at each change to the `current_data` table, see if value is changed or if an id got deleted and insert a row, it seems to be somewhat excessive.

I'm looking for a way to do this in bulk, within one or two queries. In particular, I'm looking for a query which checks the corresponding `id` in `update_history` for each `id` in `current_data`, and if value mismatches for the latest `tstamp` or `id` in `update_history` is not found, inserts a row with `id`, `value`, `stamp`, `delete`=0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do this on an ongoing basis then I would read up about [TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) in MySQL.

Otherwise if this is a one-off task then you can do it in two queries. First to identify all rows in the current table that have a value different to the last value in the history and insert a new row in the history

```
INSERT INTO update_history SELECT cd.id,cd.value,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0
FROM current_data cd 
INNER JOIN update_history uh1 ON ( cd.id=uh1.id AND cd.value!=uh1.value AND uh1.delete=0)
WHERE uh1.stamp = (
SELECT MAX(stamp) 
FROM update_history uh2
WHERE uh2.id=cd.id
)
```

Then to identify any current rows that don't have an entry in the history

```
INSERT INTO update_history SELECT cd.id,cd.value,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),0
FROM current_data cd 
LEFT JOIN update_history uh1 ON cd.id=uh1.id 
WHERE uh1.id IS NULL
```

I believe there are a few flaws in your design. What happens, for example, if two changes happen at the same time (in terms of timestamps)? How do you identify which one was "first"? You may need a unique id on the history table.